# INSERT with Multiple select SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I'm trying to insert data into `dv_user_akun` table with value that I've selected from another table. Please take a look.

```
INSERT INTO dv_user_akun (user_id, nik, username, password, kode_tipe, flag) 
    SELECT 
        (SELECT
             CASE
                WHEN right(max(user_id), 8) IS NULL
                  THEN 'USR00000001' 
                  ELSE ('USR-' + RIGHT('0000000' + cast(right(max(user_id), 7) + 1 as nvarchar), 7)) 
             END user_id 
         FROM 
             dv_user_akun) as user_id,
        (SELECT 
             Nip, Nip, '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055', PositionCode, 1 
         FROM
             Employee 
         WHERE
             Nip NOT IN (SELECT Nik FROM dv_user_akun))
```

I get this error

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list.
>   The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have anything in your select statement. I've changed your subqueries to proper joins rather than the old style ansi joins that you have there. The only problem I still have is that you appear to be using the field Nip to insert into both nik and username fields;

```
INSERT INTO dv_user_akun (user_id, nik, username, password, kode_tipe, flag)
SELECT 
a.user_id
,b.Nip
,b.Nip
,b.pass
,b.PositionCode
,b.number
FROM (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN right(max(user_id), 8) IS NULL
                    THEN 'USR00000001'
                ELSE ('USR-' + RIGHT('0000000' + cast(right(max(user_id), 7) + 1 AS NVARCHAR), 7))
                END user_id
        FROM dv_user_akun
        ) a
CROSS JOIN
(
        SELECT 
            Nip
            ,'81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055' pass
            ,PositionCode
            ,1 number
        FROM Employee
        WHERE Nip NOT IN (
                SELECT Nik
                FROM dv_user_akun
                )
        ) b
```

Comment: thanks it works. you make a little mistake there `SELECT 
            ,Nip`